# Android Studio Возникает ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class FragmentСategoriesSecond extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    ListView userList;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;


    public FragmentCategoriesSecond() {           
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ex3, null);
        userList = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        // создаем базу данных
        databaseHelper.create_db();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // открываем подключение
        db = databaseHelper.open();
        //получаем данные из бд в виде курсора
        userCursor =  db.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
        // определяем, какие столбцы из курсора будут выводиться в ListView
        String[] headers = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME};
        // создаем адаптер, передаем в него курсор
        userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
        userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        // Закрываем подключение и курсор
        db.close();
        userCursor.close();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button: {
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button1: {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Появляется ошибка

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2019-03-19 16:26:53.033 28931-28931/ru.forestcode.receptapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.forestcode.receptapp, PID: 28931
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at ru.forestcode.receptapp.FragmentCategoriesSecond.onResume(FragmentCategoriesSecond.java:61)
        at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2399)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1171)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:815)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:483)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это значит, что нужно открыть файл разметки (`ex3.xml`) и обнаружить, что там нет `<ListView>` вообще или у него другой `id` (не `list_item`) и исправить ситуацию.

То есть причина ошибки в том, что вызов `v.findViewById(R.id.list_item);` не нашёл элемент с таким `id` и вернул `null`.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Глаз замылился за целый день и перед носом проблему не увидел)